# How to use PayPal checkout in a Cordova app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cordova, paypal, quasar-framework

Hi I'm currently trying to open the PayPal checkout experience in a Cordova app, if I test it in my browser it works fine but however when I create my Cordova app it doesn't load the checkout experience app.
Advise on what to do would be great.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Checkout must be opened in an [app viewer that has an address bar](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/info-security-guidelines/#secure-applications), such as a Safari View Controller or Chrome Custom Tab. A WKWebView or similar cannot be used.